# .NET: TopItem property of ListView fails with “ShowGroups” on

Tags: listview, scrollbar

I tried a solution from [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8935186/net-topitem-property-of-listview-fails-with-showgroups-true) provided by "Jonas" and it gets me a TopItem index, however it doesn't work as expected, I'm assuming because of my groups. My listview is of folders and files and my groups are Folders, Word docs, Excel docs, PowerPoint docs, Acrobat docs, and then everything else.

There are 40 folders and the indexes go from 0 to 39.

The next group is Word, and the first few item indexes are 52, 57, 60, 61, 64, 73. That would lead me to believe the indexes are assigned in order they are written into the listview.

I scroll so that my second Word item is the top item (index 57). I issue my refresh (confirmed index is 57) and update the listview.

After the update has ended and just prior to setting the topitem the listview appears blank. The current top item is 0 and the name is the first folder. I set the top item, the top index show is 386 or roughly the 85th item in the list.

Code to Get and Set Top item

```
mMyItem = RealtopItem()

If Not ExpTree1.SelectedItem Is Nothing Then
    lv1.Update()
End If

lv1.TopItem = mMyItem
```

RealTopItem Code

```
Public Function RealtopItem() As ListViewItem

Dim i As Integer = 0

While (i < lv1.Items.Count AndAlso Not lv1.ClientRectangle.Contains(lv1.Items(i).Bounds))
    i = i + 1
End While

Return lv1.Items(i)
```

End Function
Even setting the topitem twice, as some have suggested, does not work. I also tried invalidate instead of Update.

Also, even when the top item is a folder (index matches actual item count) it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly the answer, but it's a solution that works for how I want it to.

Basically, I eliminated the need to rebuild the listview.  Without the rebuild, the scroll position as well as selected items remains the same.  The items I updated do not reflect their new name, so in the renaming functions, I set the name of the text to what the new file name should be.

This works exactly as I need it to.  I don't have to rebuild the list view because I am not adding any files.  I will need to create a solution for the item I delete.